# Osmosis plugin map-writer doesn't exist

Tags: osmosis, mapsforge

I need to create my own mapsforge map file...

1. My system is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
2. I've installed osmosis via apt
3. Since link in [official documentation](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Map-Writer.md) is not working i've found plugin file [here](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/sonatype-snapshots-cache/org/mapsforge/mapsforge-map-writer/0.4.0-SNAPSHOT/) and downloaded it
4. Following [this documentation](https://github.com/cgeo/cgeo/wiki/How-to-create-your-own-offline-maps) I placed file in ~/.openstreetmap/osmosis/plugins/
5. Downloaded osm.pbf file from geofabrik
6. Run

   osmosis --read-xml file=poland-latest.osm.pbf --mapfile-writer file=test.map

And i' getting this error:

```
lis 17, 2014 10:40:02 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run 
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.40.1 
lis 17, 2014 10:40:02 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run 
INFO: Preparing pipeline. 
lis 17, 2014 10:40:02 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main 
SEVERE: Execution aborted. org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Task type mapfile-writer doesn't exist.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.TaskManagerFactoryRegister.getInstance(TaskManagerFactoryRegister.java:60)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.buildTasks(Pipeline.java:50)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.prepare(Pipeline.java:112)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:86)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:328)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:408)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:351)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)
```

Seems like osmosis don't see the plugin, but i've done everything according to docummentation... I've also tried to place plugin file in other localization (/usr/share/osmosis, /usr/share/osmosis/plugins), but still not works..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer...

Following another documentation i've placed plugin file in sub-folder /plugins in current folder - it works.

Comment: @AndreJ - of course - sorry :/